# How to validate a D-Bus property when using gdbus-codegen skeleton

Tags: c++, glib, dbus, gdbus

I'm creating a service on D-Bus using `gdbus` and `gdbus-codegen`.

Introspection is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
                      "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<node>
  <interface name="com.example.foo">

    <property name="Bar" type="s" access="readwrite" />

  </interface>
</node>
```

I'm executing `gdbus-codegen` like this:

```
gdbus-codegen --interface-prefix com.example --generate-c-code=foo foo.xml
```

And my main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.h"

void OnBarChanged(GObject * gobject, GParamSpec * pspec, gpointer user_data)
{
  std::cout << "Bar: " << foo_get_bar((Foo *)gobject) << std::endl;
}

void OnBusNameAquired(GDBusConnection * connection,
                      const gchar *     name,
                      gpointer          user_data)
{
  Foo * foo = foo_skeleton_new();

  g_signal_connect(foo, "notify::bar", G_CALLBACK(&OnBarChanged), NULL);

  g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export(G_DBUS_INTERFACE_SKELETON(foo),
                                   connection,
                                   "/com/example/foo",
                                   NULL);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Testing DBus properties" << std::endl;

  GMainLoop * loop;
  loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
  g_bus_own_name(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION,
                 "com.example.foo",
                 G_BUS_NAME_OWNER_FLAGS_NONE,
                 NULL,
                 OnBusNameAquired,
                 NULL,
                 NULL,
                 NULL);
  g_main_loop_run(loop);
  return 0;
}
```

This works as expected and I'm able to set and get properties using:

```
gdbus call --session --dest com.example.foo --object-path /com/example/foo --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set "com.example.foo" "Bar" "<'baz'>"
```

and

```
gdbus call --session --dest com.example.foo --object-path /com/example/foo --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get "com.example.foo" "Bar"
(<'baz'>,)
```

**The problem:**

I want to validate the setting of the property synchronously and be able to return an error if it fails. How can this be accomplished using the `gdbus-codegen`-generated code?

**PS:**

The code leaks and is generally not production ready. I'm fine with that for now :-)

**Edit**

After continues research, it seems like the D-Bus properties are using the underlying `GObject` property feature. Is it possible to install a custom validator when all of this is set up by the `gdbus-codegen`-code?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the [`GDBusInterfaceSkeleton::g-authorize-method`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusInterfaceSkeleton.html#GDBusInterfaceSkeleton-g-authorize-method) signal from your `foo` skeleton. Your callback will be invoked for every D-Bus method invocation handled by your exported object — you can match on [`org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties) calls and do the validation then.

There’s an example of this (for arbitrary method calls, not D-Bus property setting; but the principle is the same) in flatpak: https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/blob/c915f73b41688a7dc2ec7f0ab2fbcf1a7c738841/system-helper/flatpak-system-helper.c#L1192